# TypeScript Will Not Let Me Set Value of Object in Array

Tags: typescript

Why will TypeScript not let me set the value of an object inside an array that I have the exact location of?

```
list: AdminDefinitionType[];
activeIndex: number;

async updateDefinition(id: keyof AdminDefinitionType, value: string | number | boolean) {
  if (value === this.list[this.activeIndex][id]) {
    return true; // No Change
  } else {
    this.list[this.activeIndex][id] = value;  // 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never' - WTF???
    const definition: AdminDefinitionType = await clerk.update(this.list[this.activeIndex])
  }
},
```

I feel like I have tried everything. I thought it might be because it may be thinking active index could be out of bounds, but I wrapped it in an `if` to ensure it was and still no luck.

How can I fix this error?

---

**Update**

```
export type AdminDefinitionType = {
  id?: number;
  name: string;
  sort: number;
  disabled: boolean;
};
```

This is my admin definition type. There are quite a few more props that don't need to be posted here, but they are all typed as strings and not optional.

Comment: How is `AdminDefinitionType` defined ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the type for the key. You can do this with a generic

```
  async updateDefinition<K extends keyof AdminDefinitionType>(id: K, value: AdminDefinitionType[K]) {
    if (value === this.list[this.activeIndex][id]) {
      return true; // No Change
    } else {
      this.list[this.activeIndex][id] = value; // OK
      const definition: AdminDefinitionType = await clerk.update(this.list[this.activeIndex])
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCATAtgSwHYAiwAZvjjDhHgCrKoC8cA3gFBxw4YD8AXHHgFcsAI2BQA3G34BDLMD4BnGFHwBzSewXQYfQSLEa4GHAunCANsAx9hECJel5JAX0ksAxuekKFcAGJ2zCxS5iY66Nj4RKR45JQ0dADaALpwjClS0u4UAG7AAJJ4GKBpcAAMbuzeiHjucAJgGNIwwNFkFFQAPADScKAtRb4A1sCIEMQRuIQk7fG0KAB8ABScfN0ANHA50uYC8pNRM7EdCSiJ3ckAlEHs7DgTS9u7DPSMMAAWJgB0oUqJH98srkCkVQMlEpwrjdbuwoMAYAIoHgEFA9uI4AB6DFwAByEDgAGF3o5VMApOxnH1zApUKwYewAQofmF-p8mUCcHlCsUQODIaUnmjMdiAPLdcm3dxUJRGI5xKh8TBTNrHOZ0UrSADu0nIcE8YiGXwaTRaS0ZzL%205o5XNBvMuEucUkdziAA)

Comment: You The Man!!! - I would love to better understand why this works though. Can you point me towards a resource I can read?

Comment: The compiler needs to ensure the value you are passing is the right one for the key. That's what the generic is doing. More on generics here : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html